# What is a "user pool" in Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I see the term "user pool" in lot of amazon documentation, but I can not understand what it is. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the AWS blog post announcement [New - Your User Pools for Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-user-pools-for-amazon-cognito/):

> With the user pools feature, you can create your own user directory that can scale to hundreds of millions of users, and is fully managed so you don’t have to worry about the heavy lifting associated with building, securing, and scaling authentication to your apps. This feature also provides enhanced security functionality such as email verification, phone number verification, and multi-factor authentication. As an app developer, you already had the option to use an external identity provider such as Amazon, Facebook, Google, Twitter or Digits for this purpose using the Cognito feature that we now call Federated Identity Pools.

Comment: what is user directory?

Comment: It is like a database with all users of your application containing details such as user names, email addresses, names etc. AWS has created a full service around the database with additional features like the ones mentioned above.